# Firefox extension : how do I make my content script execute in every URL?

Tags: javascript, permissions, firefox-addon

I am creating an extension which detects the user's cursor movements. In a tab, if the user doesn't move for 10s, the tab is refreshed and redirected to a specific URL. I want the redirection to happen no matter the current URL is. **My script is working, but the user has to go on the extension for each URL and manually authorize it to execute on this URL. How can I make this extension work on every URL ? **

I am using ManifestV3.
I wrote my content script as following :

```
let lastMouseMoveTime = Date.now();

document.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
  lastMouseMoveTime = Date.now();
});

function checkMouseActivity() {
  const currentTime = Date.now();
  if (currentTime - lastMouseMoveTime >= 10000) {
    // no move for 10s
    console.log("Redirect user");
    window.location.href = "https://redirection.url";
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({ redirect: true });
  } else {
    setTimeout(checkMouseActivity, 1000);
  }
}

checkMouseActivity();
```

And here are the permissions I am asking for in the manifest.json file :

```
 "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "scripting"],
 "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
       {
           "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
           "js": ["content.js"]
       }
   ]
```

According to the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns), my content script should execute on all URLs. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: See https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/request-permissions-at-install-time-manifest-v3/121543